# Book with like 10 kids with powers and invading aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

A few years ago I read a book (part of a series, I'm pretty sure) where there were kids with powers, and their names were numbers (One, Two, etc). I also remember that there was an invading alien species. I forgot what the book(s) were called though.

Information:

1. Kids with powers; their names were numbers.
2. Alien species invading the planet.

Comment: This isn't a lot to go on. Please take a look at [these checklists](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and see if you can recall any more details about the story or characters, which you can then [edit] into your question. It'd improve the odds of you getting a correct answer.

Comment: Welcome new user.  Heh - this would have to be the easiest question ever asked on here!

Answer (score 20):

The [Lorien Legacies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorien_Legacies) books deal with kids with powers (the "Loric" aliens, only a few survivors of which live on earth passing as teenagers) and alien invaders (the "Mogadorians").

All the Loric are numbered, albeit numbers One Two and Three have been murdered by the start of the first book, titled [I am Number Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Number_Four).  Later books introduce higher numbered Loric characters.

[image: I am Number Four - Cover]

Answer (score 0):

Could this be Umbrella Academy?

It's a graphic novel (as well as a TV show) and the kids are all called by number.  There are seven, which is close enough to ten for the purposes of the question.

Comment: Can you explain why this might match?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots SPOILERS IF YOU KEEP READING!  In the second season of the show it is revealed that Sir Reginald Hargreeves (whom adopted all of the numbered children with powers) is an alien.  This is also based on a graphic novel, which I am unfamiliar with, regardless it is feasible that said alien species may invade at some point.  They certainly seem to have some vested interest in Earth.

Comment: Well, this is a book they're asking about, so it being the graphic novel would match. :) Anyhow, please add more details to your answer. You can make a spoiler quote with ">? " at the beginning of a line if you're worried about revealing details.